# Uploading Image with other information with ajax, jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Im having problems uploading information with an image utilizing ajax + php. I get an illegal invocation message when trying to add the dataResult.file = form_data; as you can see on the code below.

I would greatly appreciate any help! I am pretty stuck on this and have searched stackoverflow quite a bit for an answer that can help me out.

```
function uploadImage (upFile,userId,description,category) {
    console.log("We have reached the point where we connect to the service to upload the image...");
    var dataResult = {};
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file',upFile[0]);
    console.log("Is the information on the form data variable?");
    console.log(form_data);
    dataResult.file = form_data;
    dataResult.idUser = userId;
    dataResult.description = description; 
    dataResult.nameCat = category;

    console.log("Description " + dataResult.description);
    console.log("Id User " + dataResult.idUser);
    console.log("name Cat " + dataResult.nameCat);

    console.log("This is the information that is being sent thorugh ajax");
    console.log(dataResult);

    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/App/www/classes/actionsPhotos/uploadPhoto.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: dataResult,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("All is good and working.");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorInfo){
                console.log("There was an error: ");
                console.log(errorInfo);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this by switching up the code a little bit, here is the new code for anyone that is having this same issue.

function uploadImage (upFile,userId,description,category) {
    console.log("We have reached the point where we connect to the service to upload the image...");
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file',upFile[0]);
    form_data.append('idUser',userId);
    form_data.append('description',description);
    form_data.append('nameCat',category);

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/App/www/classes/actionsPhotos/uploadPhoto.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("All is good and working.");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorInfo){
            console.log("There was an error: ");
            console.log(errorInfo);
        }
    });
```

}